# Finding an orthogonal matrix P such that $P^TAP$ is diagonal (this time dim=3) - answer check

Tags: linear-algebra

I hate doing matrices like this, I am really sorry.

$[4,0,-2]$

$[0,2,-2]$

$[-2,-2,3]$

I got $[1,2,2]$, $[2,-2,1]$ $[2,-1,-2]$ for eigenvalues 0,3 and 6 respectively

I'm checking it on paper right now, getting that other question wrong has shaken my confidence I am sorry to say.

Comment: I did want to point out that, to make an orthogonal matrix out of those eigenvectors, you need to divide the entries by 3. You seem to have some $\pm$ signs wrong.

Comment: the third vector is not true. The correct one is $(2,1,-2)$

Comment: Just found that, thanks @Mohamed

Answer (score 1):

Let us put $u_1=(1,2,2),u_2=(2,-2,1),u_3=(2,1,-2)$. We have : $\|u_k\|=3$ for  $k=1,2,3$ then : $$P=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&2\\2&-2&1\\2&1&-2 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$D=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&6\end{pmatrix}$$